# DataFrame Python filter Columns Array of Strings

Tags: python, dataframe

How would I filter out columns that contain an Array of Strings from a DataFrame in Python that contain words from a given array.

For Example:

```
    Name       List    
    'A' ['ahh', 'help', 'please']    
    'B' ['I', 'am', 'trying']    
    'C' ['my', 'best', 'please']
```

words to filter

```
 ['ahh', 'please', 'maybe']
```

So since both rows `'A'         ['ahh', 'help', 'please']` and `'B'         ['I', 'am', 'trying']` contain words from the filter list, they would be removed.

Also, say the entire list of the row existed in the array that I wanted to remove, for example my list to filter by was ['please', 'help', 'I', 'am', 'begging' 'ahh']
And then the only row deleted was row 'A'         ['ahh', 'help', 'please'] since the entire list exists in the filter list, how could I do that?

Comment: _How would I filter out columns that contain an Array of Strings from a DataFrame in Python that contain words from a given array_ What have you tried? This question is readily answered with with a Google seach.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service. Please read the following documentation, then [edit] and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors) as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).